# IDEA doesn't recognize typegoose type of model

Tags: intellij-idea, typegoose

Trying to include `@typegoose/typegoose`, followed all installation step for it and just put model which has been provided in example

```
import { prop, getModelForClass } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

class User {
    @prop()
    public name?: string;
}

const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);
```

IDEA couldn't recognize methods from `UserModel` like 'create' etc.
[image: screen]

What's more interesting - just put in empty folder the same `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` and put in index this code:

```
import { prop, getModelForClass } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

class User {
    @prop()
    public name?: string;

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public jobs?: string[];
}

const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);
```

and IDEA see what's needed
[image]

Comment: what are the versions being used here? (versions of `mongoose`, `typegoose`, `@types/mongoose` and `typescript`)

Comment: `"typescript": "^4.1.3"` `"mongoose": "^5.11.10"` `"@typegoose/typegoose": "^7.4.6"`   `"@types/mongoose": "^5.10.3"`

Comment: did you already try using the highest supported version of mongoose (from typegoose), which is `5.10.18`?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work in other editors as well (tried with VSCode):

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the inrferred type of `UserModel` is `any`, so there are no expected methods in completion. Looks as if the typings (`d.ts` files) of the `@typegoose/typegoose` package have to be re-worked